# How to disable Cascading Dropdown with selected value?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

While updating record, I want to disable ajax Cascading drop down with selected value.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on this one or provide the code that you have already tried.

Comment: i have tried dropdownID.Enabled=false and cascadingdropdownid.Enabled=false. but it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the dropdown you could add a the following snippet of client-side code;

```
function DisableDDL() {
$('#<%= ddlName.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}

function PageLoad(sender, args) {
$find("ddlName").add_populated(DisableDDL);
}
```